# Python parse XML files with HTML content

Tags: python, xml

I use an API to get some XML files but some of them contain HTML tags without escaping them. For example, `<br>` or `<b></b>`

I use this code to read them, but the files with the HTML raise an error. I don't have access to change manually all the files. Is there any way to parse the file without losing the HTML tags?

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

xml = ...#here is the api to receive the xml file
dom = parse(xml)
strings = dom.getElementsByTagName("string")
```

Comment: How about replacing `<br>` with `<br />` before parsing the xml? And I don't see what's wrong with `<b></b>`? Also, consider using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead of minidom; minidom can cause memory leaks.

Comment: The xml variable is a file_path. So, how can I replace the tag before parsing? Can you give an example of this code with ElementTree and replacing as an answer, to see if it works and accept your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the xml file as a string, and fix the malformed tags before you parse it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open(xml) as xml_file: # open the xml file for reading
    text= xml_file.read() # read its contents
text= text.replace('<br>', '<br />') # fix malformed tags
document= ET.fromstring(text) # parse the string
strings= document.findall('string') # find all string elements
```

Comment: For a reason I cannot understand, if I use `text = text.replace('<br>', '<br />') ` the string after the tag disappear. If I use `text = text.replace('<br>', "")` all the string is there, but obviously without the new line

Answer (score 2):

If you can use third-party libs I suggest you to use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) it can handle xml as well as html and also it parses broken markup, also providing easy to use api.